# PL/SQL need assistance on this

Tags: plsql

Question is: First create a table called amttopay that has three fields: rec_no, idno and amt (make amount a numeric field that can hold 3 decimal places. You are also going to use a copy of the donor table for this assignment. Take in a number that matches an idno on the donor table. Check the yrgoal for that record. If it is larger than 500 then double it to create a new goal and write four records on the amttopay table containing the quarterly payment number (1 through 4), the idno, and the quarterly amount to pay to achieve the new goal. If it is not larger than 500 then add 50% to the goal to make the new goal and process it by writing the four records with the same information.

I created the table amttopay, which is blank:

```
SQL> create table amttopay
 2  (rec_no number(3),
 3  idno number(3),
 4  amt number(8,3));

Table created.
```

I also have the donor table so you can see for reference:

```
SQL> select *
2  from newloop;

  IDNO  NAME            STADR           CITY       ST ZIP   DATEFST       YRGOAL
```

---

```
11111 Stephen Daniels 123 Elm St      Seekonk    MA 02345 03-JUL-98        500

12121 Jennifer Ames   24 Benefit St   Providence RI 02045 24-MAY-97        400

22222 Carl Hersey     24 Benefit St   Providence RI 02045 03-JAN-98

23456 Susan Ash       21 Main St      Fall River MA 02720 04-MAR-92        100

33333 Nancy Taylor    26 Oak St       Fall River MA 02720 04-MAR-92         50

34567 Robert Brooks   36 Pine St      Fall River MA 02720 04-APR-98         50
```

My code is:

```
SET VERIFY OFF
DECLARE
v_idno    donornew.idno%TYPE :=&input_idno;
v_yrgoal  donornew.yrgoal%TYPE;
BEGIN
 SELECT idno, yrgoal INTO v_idno, v_yrgoal
 FROM newloop
 WHERE idno = v_idno;
 IF v_yrgoal > 500 THEN
      v_newgoal := v_yrgoal * 2;
 ELSE v_yrgoal < 500 THEN
      v_newgoal := v_yrgoal * 1.5;
    END IF;
 UPDATE newloop
 SET yrgoal = v_newgoal
 WHERE idno = v_idno;
 COMMIT;
 END;
  /
 SET VERIFY ON
```

I do not know how to fix my code to run it to select an idno, take the yrgoal run the if loop and spit it out to those 4 record in the new table.

Comment: Look into CURSORS: Select your data into a cursor, loop over the cursor and insert the results into the new table.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen will that answer below take it and make four quarterly payments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi use cursor to do it in loop
and you can using returning operator to get a new value after update and insert the records in your log table.

```
DECLARE

  CURSOR NEWLOOP_CURS IS
    SELECT IDNO, YRGOAL FROM NEWLOOP;

  V_NEWGOAL      NEWLOOP.YRGOAL%TYPE;


BEGIN
  FOR INDX IN NEWLOOP_CURS
  LOOP
    IF INDX.YRGOAL > 500
    THEN
      V_NEWGOAL := INDX.YRGOAL * 2;
    ELSE
      INDX.YRGOAL < 500 
      THEN V_NEWGOAL := INDX.YRGOAL * 1.5;
    END IF;
    UPDATE NEWLOOP 
    SET YRGOAL = V_NEWGOAL 
    WHERE IDNO = INDX.IDNO;
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Will that create four records in the new loop table?